# Symfony2 decode and compare pass

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, encode

I need to make a form:

- when I choose user from list I will get an input where user will be able to write password (for selected user).
- And I must compare if the password agrees with the pass from database.
  I found one solution on stack. But I asking if meaby there is other way to make it?
  Any ideas?

here is what I already done:

**Controller:**

```
public function UserAction(Request $request){
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserIncType());


        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

            $form->bind($request);
                if ($form->isValid()){
                $valuePass=$form->get('Password')->getData();
                $valueUser=$form->get('User')->getData();

                    $security_encoder = null;
                    $userRepo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainCoreBundle:User');
                    $user = $userRepo->findById($valueUser);

                    $security_encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
                    $password = $request->get('password');


            }
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('permits_show'));

}
```

How to decode pass from database and comapre it with pass from form?

Or is there any other way to make it?

Comment: I see two problems, 1) You are using a controller to do this when Symfony has a whole chapter on configuring security, and 2) You don't decode the persisted password, you compare an encoded password from the form with the one in the database.

Comment: Its example. But how to decode it and compare? or any other way to do it?

Comment: You don't decode it.  Please refer to http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html, if you have any questions about that, then update your question.